# Toolbar changes color in full screen mode

Tags: cocoa, osx-lion

I have an OS X application, written for Lion, and when the app enters into full screen mode the toolbar changes its background color to white (see the attached images)

[image: Toolbar non full screen mode]
[image: Toolbar full screen mode]

What I have to do for having the same background color in non full and full screen mode ?

Thank you

Fab.

Answer (score 0):

I removed

```
[window setBackgroundColor:[NSColor whiteColor]];
```

from applicationDidFinishLaunching and the toolbar started mantain its color also in full screen mode.